# How to create a hyperlink to switch between different language in Sitecore?

Tags: multilingual

I want to create a two hyperlink English|Malay so that when user click on any of the link and the website language should changed in the sitecore. I am new to Sitecore and I really have no idea how can i achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

You're not saying much about how you generate the page, if it's view renderings, or so.

But in general, you can append the desired language code to any url. Use the `sc_lang` query parameter. `http://yourhost.com/yoururl?sc_lang=en-MA`.

Answer (score 2):

This is really about getting the item in its different language versions, then getting the URL for each

I'll assume the item only has those 2 languages.
I'll also assume that your site is configured to embed the language in the URL

First lets get the item in each language:

```
Item tempItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(tempID);
foreach (var itemLanguage in tempItem.Languages)
{
    var item = tempItem.Database.GetItem(tempItem.ID, itemLanguage);
    if (item.Versions.Count > 0)
    {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

(Code copy/pasted from Mark Cassidy's answer to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915696/get-item-in-all-languages-in-which-it-has-a-version))

Now that you have the item in its differnt languages you can use this code for each one

```
LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item);
```